# Pulling data from database table, based on categories

Tags: mysql

I have a table which has fields like category,city,mobile and email data.
I need to create a report like: For each Category in the table i need to get count of distinct mobile and distinct email for each city

Comment: sounds like you should follow some SQL tutorials(s). come back here if you have a concrete example code (for example SQL statement) and sample data, and a specific problem with that.

Comment: I would recommend a freelancer website, this forum is not used to hire programmers to complete your task

Answer (score 0):

```
select category, count(distinct mobile), count(distinct city)
from your_table
group by category
```